# How to find a method of determining whether an acid is strong or weak given only a formula?

Tags: acid-base

I know that strong acids dissociate completely in water, and weak acids dissociate only partially. I searched for a method for finding if an acid is strong or weak given its formula, but the answer was a definitive, "You can't". My question is, what would be the best way of going about finding a pattern between strong and weak acids based on their formula?

Comment: Chemistry is semi-empirical science. There are few laws, many semi-empirical and empirical rules and many exceptions. There is no shortcut to learn it. First you have to memorize or search for the facts to know them. Later, when knowledge and experience comes, you will learn to see patterns in the facts, related to underlying known or unknown principles. It will allow you to reduce the data you need to remember or search for. But there will be always a lot of behavior that cannot be predicted from a simple rule set. Many facts can be predicted, but it may be inaccurate and very complicated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_dissociation_constant#Factors_that_affect_pKa_values

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57574/is-there-a-formula-or-way-to-determine-whether-an-acid-is-a-strong-one-or-a-weak

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/105242/does-concentration-or-pka-define-acid-strength

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:  You can't.

The longer is answer is that there are some guidelines.

In most high-school and intro-level college general chemistry classes, students are taught that there are 6 common strong acids:  $\ce{HCl, HBr, HI, HNO3, H2SO4 and HClO4}$.  There are others, but these are the most common.  If the acid you are interested in is not one of these, it is likely to be a weak acid.

The only sure way to know is to look up the $\ce{Ka}$ or $\ce{pKa}$ of the acid.  Strong acids have $\ce{pKa's}$ below 0.  For example, hydrochloric acid has a $\ce{pKa}$ around -6, and nitric acid's is around -1.  Weak acids have $\ce{pKa's}$ greater than 0.

There might be some debate around where the cut-off line is between weak and strong acids; I've used zero here, but I've seen 1 used elsewhere.  That part isn't really important.